# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [Twitter widget Wordpress API]

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, foreach

Im currently developing a website for my exams. I only need a twitter ticker, and found a great plugin for WordPress.

Now the problemm is that i get the error stated below :

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /public/sites/www.wijkcoach.nl/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/twitter-feed-ticker/ag_twitterfeed_widget.php on line 53

**The code stated in this line is as following :**

```
foreach ($tweets->statuses as $entry) {
        echo '<a href="http://twitter.com/'. $twittername .'#stream-item-tweet-' . $entry->id_str . '" target="_blank">' . $entry->text . '<i>' . date('F d Y', strtotime($entry->created_at)) . '</i></a>';
```

}

Now i really need this to work or i wont pass my exams..

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

`print($tweets)` gives me the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)
```

Comment: Post your array `print_r($tweets)` and update your question

Comment: Please also use code formating (ctrl-k)

Comment: Edited my question, sorry im kinda a php nub